# disable title/header on helm-projectile result frame

Tags: helm

I use `helm-projectile-find-file` and `helm-projectile-ag` on a regular basis. My issue is I want to remove the following lines `C-j: Preview file (keeping session)` and `Projectile files` from the result frame in order to fill the screen space only with worthwhile information. Googling doesn't help so much, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can advice `helm-projectile-find-file` to disable the header-line (do the same for `helm-projectile-ag`):

```
(advice-add 'helm-projectile-find-file :around
            (lambda (oldfun &rest args)
              (let ((helm-display-header-line nil))
                (apply oldfun args))))
```

Or set `helm-display-header-line` to nil to disable it everywhere. I don't think you can remove the title line.

Comment: works for me, thanks